# Element wise between a 2-D numpy array and a list

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to apply a function

```
def lead(x,n):
    if n>0:
        x = np.roll(x,-n)
        x[-n:]=1
    return x
```

to each element of Qxx, a 2-D numpy array (121,121), BUT WITH ROLLING the "n" argument
from a list [0,1,2,3,4,....121] for example and in a element wise way.

the following code is working but SLOW !

```
xx = [[lead(qx,n) for n in range(len(qx))] for qx in Qxx]
```

how can I do it with apply_long_axis or map or...

smtg like :

```
xx = np.apply_along_axis(lead,1,arr = Qxx,n=range(121))
```

thanks

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is not a performance tool; plus it only iterates on one array.   Show us what this code does.  Others have asked how to do a different `roll` for each row of a 2d array, but I think there's more going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be much faster:

```
list(map(lambda x: lead(Qxx[x], x), range(121)))
```

Performance:

The OP's solution:

```
%%timeit

[[lead(qx,n) for n in range(len(qx))] for qx in Qxx]

178 ms ± 3.32 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

My solution:

```
%%timeit

list(map(lambda x: lead(Qxx[x], x), range(121)))

1.63 ms ± 60.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Data:

```
Qxx = np.array(np.tile(np.arange(121), 121)).reshape((121, 121))
```

Comment: Which is more significant, the use of `map` or `shift`

Comment: I had just posed the same question to myself, @hpaulj! The answer is `map`. Using `map` and the OP own function, it is slightly faster than when using `shift`. I am going to update my answer accordingly.

Comment: Usually the difference between list comprehension and list/map isn't great.   But I'm not at my computer so can't do any testing.

Comment: You are right, @hpaulj! I have just found out that my solution is not equivalent to the OP's one: his *nested* for loop produces 121 lists of 121 lists. I am not sure whether the OP really wants that.